# String Manipulation in SQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a varchar table column containing information by this convention:

#### model_parts-name

EX:

```
A85_BATTERY CONNECTOR
A85_CAMERA-BACK
C101V_UPPER SHELL
```

I want to split this column into model name and parts name.
how can I do that ?

Comment: Is not a hyphen there all the time??

Comment: only underscore exist to separate model name from parts name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INSTR` to find `_` index and use `LEFT/RIGHT` to get part of string.

```
CREATE TABLE tab(name VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO tab
VALUES ('A85_BATTERY CONNECTOR'),('A85_CAMERA-BACK'), ('C101V_UPPER SHELL');

SELECT 
  name, 
  LEFT(name, INSTR(name, '_') - 1) AS model_name,
  RIGHT(name, LENGTH(name) - INSTR(name, '_')) AS part_name
FROM tab
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7127e/5/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score -2):

You can create a view and use `substr(model_parts-name,instr(model_parts-name,'_'))`  function column

Comment: no sub-string function will not work... because i have to find the underscore (_) symbol from each string.. and split it into two..

Comment: You can use it easily, let me provide full solution.